# My Python IF Statement is not working and it should be, I have no idea why not

Tags: python, if-statement

[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dkeY.png) I'm making a project on python and this IF statement is not executing the required response even tho the two values are exactly the same. songs[random_number] and user_guess have the same values Please help, I have tried everything and made sure the two variables are IDENTICAL but it is still not working. It should be printing out 'WELL DONE' but is not.
Thanks
Jack

```
if songs[random_number] == user_guess:
        print("Well Done, you have guessed correctly!")
        guess_counter = guess_counter + 1
else:
     guess_counter = guess_counter + 1
     print("Incorrect, Try Again!")


#BELOW IS THE 2 VALUES PRINTED OUT BEFORE THE IF EXECUTES
Welcome to the game!
Y_____3_____   by:Busted

Enter your guess at the full title of the song:Year 3000
Year 3000

Year 3000
Incorrect, Try Again!
```

Comment: Give an example of an entry from 'songs'. Also, you have a syntax error: guess_counter +

Comment: Computers don't get to lie about their branch comparison, so I don't believe you. Maybe if you can prove to us that `songs[random_number]` and `user_guess` are indeed the same, by showing more code to turn this into a [mcve], that would change matters.

Comment: Fixed the syntax error. An example could be the word 'happier' which is stored in the songs list

Comment: @Jack Is it possible for you to print  songs[random_number] and user_guess just before this if statement executes? Place the print outs in your question above.

Comment: Never start doubting if statements :-) Maybe there's something "random" that sounds more suspicious...

Comment: I've added an image to my post with the two values printed out before the IF executes, and the two values are the same but the IF still doesn't do what I want it to do. Thanks

Comment: Did you add the empty line between the prints, or is it coming from the 'song'?

Comment: I didn't add the empty line and the 'song[random_number]' is printed first so it must be from that?? If it is how would I get rid of it? Thanks

Comment: Look at how songs are added to the array. If they are loaded from a file, a new line is probably picked up as well. I can't say much without looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a `input()` statement, which always returns a string type. Often times Boolean checks with binary operators don't return expected results because the `type()` is different. Try checking if not only the characters are identical but also the data types.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now, if you have the same issue with an extra line being read in from an external file visit this link to see if it can solve your issue.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-December/010357.html

Thanks for everyone who helped and identified that an extra line had been read in.

This is the line of code that needed to be modified with '[:-1]' :

```
songs.append(line[:-1])
```